# PHPExcel: how do I check save() was success?

Tags: php, phpexcel

After writing an Excel spreadsheet via PHPExcel, I need to update rows in the database.

I have:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$objWriter->save("library/profiles/reports/spreadsheet.xlsx");
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
```

I suspect that the save() method returns something, but I've not been able to find any documentation on this.

Am I able to check whether save() was a success or not, or should I just use file_exists() instead?

Answer (score 3):

From the API docs, the signature for the Writer save() methods is

```
/**
 * Save PHPExcel to file
 *
 * @param   string      $pFilename
 * @throws  PHPExcel_Writer_Exception
 */
```

So you use a try/catch block to handle any thrown exceptions

Comment: Hi Mark, just to be clear: would I be placing both the PHPExcel code and the UPDATE query code inside the try() block? I've never used a try-catch block before.

Comment: Well any of your code that works with PHPExcel could throw an exception, not simply the save method; while some methods might return a status code, they're few and far between because throwing an exception is the PHPExcel behaviour when it encounters a problem situation

Comment: All PHPExcel exceptions have a type of PHPExcel_Exception (or extend PHPExcel_Exception) so you can catch them independently of any exceptions (such as database exceptions) that the rest of your code might throw

Comment: It's just the save method I'm concerned with, but I don't understand the throw-catch block syntax enough to incorporate into what I'm doing; I don't understand where I put what.

Comment: [PHP Docs for Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and you'd put anything that might throw an exception between the `try` and the `catch`.... there's an example showing how to handle exceptions for the reader in the [PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/06-Error-Handling.md) and the Writers should be handled in exactly the same way

Answer (score 2):

http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Writer/PHPExcel_Writer_IWriter.html#methodsave
Strangely enough it seems `save()` does not return anything, so just try catch exceptions and assume everything was allright if there aren't